# Bamboo & Docker - How can i publish artifacts created in the Docker enviroment?

Tags: docker, bamboo, bamboo-artifacts

I am currently running a cicd via Docker on Bamboo and i want to create an artifact with the tests results of the unit tests.

The running Docker creates a folder with all the text results .xml-files and i tried coping them to the root directory of the agent, but that doesn't work at all. The folder only exists in the Docker environment and after the Docker is done i can't access the created files anymore.

How can i publish these Docker created files in Bamboo as an artifact?

Comment: Well there is an option in bamboo, in run docker configuration where you can bind folder from agent to docker container. I think that you just need to copy results into that folder. Check --volume option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand your question, you want your test files created in your running container to be copied to some artifact, have you tried something like this :

```
cp $SOURCE_PATH/system-tests/* $ARTIFACTS_PATH/system-tests
```

I think this should work for you.